# Get AVG() of values from table with different names

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a table :

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
    value integer,
    name varchar(100)
)
```

In my table there can be duplicate values of `name` possible with different value of `value`. Now I want to get `DISTINCT` `name` and there `avg()` `value` from the Table `data`.

I am able to get `DISTINCT` value of `name` but unable to get `avg()` of there `value`s.

Now with following Query I get `avg()` of all data :

```
select floor(avg(value)) from data
```

I know this is incorrect but I am new to SQL. I want this `select floor(avg(value))` for `distinct` values of `name`.

Data :

```
insert into data values(10, 'mnciitbhu')
insert into data values(20, 'mnciitbhu')
insert into data values(40, 'mafiya69')
insert into data values(20, 'mafiya69')
insert into data values(0, 'mafiya69')
```

Output :

```
mnciitbhu 15
mafiya69 20
```

Comment: give some example data and required output sample..??????

Comment: No shame in being new, but no harm in undertaking basic research either.

Comment: give some example data and required output sample @mnciitbhu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this because the other answers while accurate, are not detailed.

What you want to do here, are use the `grouping` and `aggregation` features of SQL.

`grouping` your results by particular fields, will divide your result set into discrete sections, which you can operate on with `aggregate` functions, to get averages, sums, counts etc, per group.

For a full list of aggregate functions, and other miscellaneous information about `group by`, you can read [12.16.1 GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

In your instance, since you want the average per name, you will need to `group by name`. This would give the following query:

```
select name, avg(value)
  from `data`
  group by name;       -- this is the important line
```

And this query will calculate the average of `value`, for each group of names in your table, returning one row per group.

One very important consideration when using `group by`, is that all fields contained in the select, must either be contained in the `group by` clause, or used in aggregate functions. If you refer to a field that isn't covered by this, you may end up with undesired indeterminate results.

From the manual [12.16.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

The importance of that paragraph cannot be overstated.  It is very easy to mis-understand how this works, arrive at a query that seems to give the desired result, but will occasionally give incorrect/undesired data.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
select name,AVG(value) as Average from data  
group by name  
order by name desc
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
name       Average
mnciitbhu   15
mafiya69    20
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select name,avg(value) from data group by name
```

Comment: In the future, be sure to provide an explanation with your answer.